# Show $\oint \exp(-i z^2)dz$ tends to zero along an arc as radius tends to infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

**Proposition**: $\displaystyle\oint \exp(-i z^2)dz$ tends to zero along an arc as radius tends to infinity. The arc is $r\exp(it),t\in[-\pi/4,0]$. I came across this in the attemp to calculate $\displaystyle\oint_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-i z^2)dz$. All references I found asserted this lightly without proof or explanation. After some time I figured out a cumbersome proof.

---

My approach is as follows:

A rough absolute value estimation: $A=|\exp(-iz^2)dz|=r\exp(r^2\sin(2t))dt$. If we choose a function of $r$, say $T(r)=(\arcsin -r^{-3/2})/2$, we have $A/dt\le r\exp(-r^{1/2})$ on $[-\pi/4,T(r)]$, and $T(r)\sim-r^{-3/2}/2$. Since $A/dt$ is convex and increasing, the integral of $A$ is no greater than $C_1 r\exp(-r^{1/2})+C_2 r^{-1/2}$, which tends to $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$.

---

Now my problem is that, since they all stated this lightly, is there any method that one can immediately gain an isight into the proposition?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Note that we have the Jordan inequality:

$\dfrac{sin(\theta)}{\theta} \geq \dfrac{2}{\pi}$ ($0 \leq\theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2} $)

put $m=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ $\Rightarrow sin(\theta) \geq m\theta$

Returning your problem:

Let $L$ denote your arc:

We have:

$\int_{L}e^{-iz^2}= \int_{\dfrac{-\pi}{4}}^{0}e^{-iR^2(cos2t+isin(2t))}.i.R.e^{it}dt =\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^{-iR^2(cos2t-isin(2t))}.i.R.e^{it}dt=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^{R^2(-icos2t-sin(2t))}.i.R.e^{it}dt$

(change of variable $t=-x$)

Hence

$\left |\int_{L}e^{-iz^2}  \right |=\left | \int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}e^{R^2(-icos2t-sin(2t))}.i.R.e^{it}dt \right | \leq R\int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2sin(2t)}dt=\dfrac{R}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2sin(t)}dt$ (change of variable $2t=\theta$)

Now applying the above inequality gives:

$\left |\int_{L}e^{-iz^2}  \right | \leq\dfrac{R}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2mt}dt =\dfrac{R}{2}.\dfrac{1}{mR^2}(1-e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}m\pi R^2}) \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ as desired.

Hope it will help you.